Nanobind C++ passing Python type to Cpp function and use it for casting
I'm creating a C++ class that handle the values passed by the client in a JSON (converted in a dict with json.loads), I make a Cpp class named Parameter and I need to pass a type to the constructor to specify the cast needed, but I don't know how to use this type (in Python is like return type_parameter(value))
I also need to convert string values to datetime object like '2024-10-10' and this is the reason for the format parameter, please let me know also how to make this thing
#include <nanobind/nanobind.h>
#include <nanobind/stl/string.h>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace nb = nanobind;
using namespace nb::literals;

class Parameter {
private:
    std::string name;
    nb::object value;

    [[nodiscard]] nb::object _get_value(
        const nb::dict& source,
        const bool& required,
        const nb::type_object& type_,
        const nb::object& default_,
        const std::string& format
    ) const {
        if (required and !source.contains(name.c_str()))
            throw std::domain_error("Parameter " + name + " is required");
        return convert(source.contains(name.c_str()) ? source[name.c_str()] : default_, type_, format);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] static nb::object convert(
        const nb::object& value,
        const nb::type_object& type_,
        const std::string& format
    ) {
        if (value.is_none() or type_.is_none())
            return value;
        return value;
    }

public:
    Parameter(
        std::string name_,
        const nb::dict& source,
        const nb::type_object& type_,
        const bool& required = false,
        const nb::object& default_ = nb::none(),
        const std::string& format = "",
        const nb::object& check = nb::none()
    ) : name(std::move(name_)) {
        value = _get_value(source, required, type_, default_, format);
        if (!check.is_none())
            check(value);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] nb::object getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
    [[nodiscard]] std::string getName() const {
        return name;
    }
};

NB_MODULE(Test3, m) {
nb::class_<Parameter>(m, "Parameter")
    .def(nb::init<
         std::string,
         const nb::dict&,
         const nb::type_object&,
         const bool&,
         const nb::object&,
         const std::string&,
         const nb::object&>(),

         "name"_a,
         "source"_a,
         "type_"_a,
         "required"_a = false,
         "default"_a = nb::none(),
         "format_"_a = "",
         "check"_a = nb::none()
    )
    .def("get_value", &Parameter::getValue)
    .def("get_name", &Parameter::getName);
}

I'm expeting to pass this parameter and use it to cast the value find in source.
(ps: correct me for anything other than the main question, I'm learning just now how cpp binding works)
